# Mocked function get triggered but toHaveBeenCalledWith do not recognize it

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, react-native-navigation

I mocked the `useNavigation()` hook from `react-naitive/navigation` but jest do not recognize it.

Jest gives me an error that the function did not get called, but when I log the function it got to be triggered.

I already tried it with wrapping they expect with `waitFor` but then I just get a typescript catch error
`Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'catch')]`

**My jest test:**

```js
jest.mock('@react-navigation/native', () => {
  const actualNav = jest.requireActual('@react-navigation/native');
  return {
    ...actualNav,
    useNavigation: () => ({
      // when I do () => { console.log('trigger') } it will be called
      navigate: jest.fn(),
    }),
    useRoute: () => ({
      params: { email: '' },
    }),
  };
});
....

  it.only('should navigate to resend screen when button is pressed', async () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(
      withStoreProvider(<EmailVerificationPending />),
    );

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(
        getByTestId('emailVerificationPendingScreen_moreInfoCta'),
      ).toBeTruthy();
    });

    fireEvent.press(getByTestId('emailVerificationPendingScreen_moreInfoCta'));

    expect(navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      RootScreens.SignUpNavigator,
      {
        screen: SignUpScreens.EmailVerificationResend,
        params: {
          email: '',
        },
      },
    );
  });
```

**Error message:**

```js
  ● features/signup/presentation/email-verification/pending-screen › should navigate to resend screen when button is pressed

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

    Expected: "RootScreens_SignUpNavigator", {"params": {"email": ""}, "screen": "SignUpScreens_EmailVerificationResend"}

    Number of calls: 0

      64 |     fireEvent.press(getByTestId('emailVerificationPendingScreen_moreInfoCta'));
      65 |
    > 66 |     expect(navigation.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
```

Comment: The error may have occurred because the function was called but not with the expected parameters.

Comment: @redbirdo No because, then it would be called and shows you the different between expected and received. The error now just give you that it did not got called.